# Errors building a DLL that depends on two other DLL's

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, java-native-interface

#### Background

I am trying to build a Java program that make use of an existing native library via JNI.  There are two components of the native project that each build a shared library:

1. A core component that builds `core.lib` and `core.dll`
2. An application component that depends on the core component, and builds `application.lib` and `application.dll`

Using SWIG, I've created an `application_wrap.c` file, and corresponding Java files so that I can use JNI to access the native library.

What I would like to do is build a new shared library (lets call it `application_jni.dll`) containing this `application_wrap.c` file, so that I can load it in my Java program like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("application_jni");
```

#### Problem

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this on Windows using the Visual Studio compiler.  Here's what I've tried:

First, compiling the `application_wrap.c` file generated by SWIG.  This produces `application_wrap.obj`, and seems to work just fine.

```
cl /I "path/to/core/headers" /I "path/to/application/headers" -c application_wrap.c
```

Next, linking the `application_wrap.obj` against the existing shared libraries to create a new shared library:

```
link /dll /out:application_jni.dll application_wrap.obj core.lib application.lib
```

This results in a large number of errors that look like this:

```
application_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__function_in_core referenced in function_in_application_wrap
```

Any idea what could be causing these errors?  I don't have a lot of experience with compiling on Windows, so I wouldn't be the least bit surprised to find that I'm missing some flags in the compile or link stages (or even misunderstanding how dll's work).

#### A Few Extra Notes

Running

```
dumpbin /exports core.lib
```

shows that all of the functions mentioned by the error messages are in fact exported by the core shared library.

#### Edit

At Pavel's suggestion I wrote a simple C program to see if it would link.  I used the same compile and link commands as above, and I ran into the same error.

The C program `test.c`:

```
#include "application.h"

int main() {
  function_in_application();
}
```

The error:

```
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__function_in_application referenced in function _main
```

Comment: Have you tried creating just a simple native `main()` which calls function(s) of your `application` ? Does that link? I don't see any obvious problems with your process, so i am eyeing the SWIG layer.

Comment: @Pavel Zdenek I wrote a simple C program to call a function in `application` and ran into the same error.  I've edited the question to include the new information.

Comment: Using SWIG sounds like a good idea, until you find out you now have two problems.  The compiler is still convinced that these functions are defined in a DLL instead of a static link library.  You'll need to chase __declspec(dllimport) in the SWIG generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries failed to link because `core.dll` and `application.dll` were compiled for 64 bit, and the default target for `cl.exe` is 32 bit.  The linker failed because i was trying to link a 32 bit `obj` file to two 64 bit `dll's`.  Compiling everything for 64 bit solved the problem.

#### A Few Things To Be Aware Of

- If you have the 64 bit compilers installed, you make `cl.exe` target 64 bit by running the the `vcvarsall.bat` script with an argument corresponding to your target platform (e.g. "amd64").  More in depth instructions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx).
- The default version of `Visual Studio Express 2010` does not install the 64 bit compilers by default.  You may need to run `setup.exe` again and check the appropriate custom install options to install them.
- The default version of `Visual Studio Express 2012` does come with 64 bit compilers.  I uninstalled the 2010 version, installed 2012, and had no problems after that.